# Switch different color from different Device

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

I have create a simple Switch but in Emulator run my color:

[image]

And on real Device:

[image]

I have assigned a theme from xml and this color is used only from emulator:

```
<style name="SCBSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#311B92</item>

    </style>
```

Device use same version of Android:

[image]

So why the real device not use this color (#311B92)?

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/protezione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:checked="false"       
        android:text="Protezione"
        android:theme="SCBSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/datas"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/datas"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datas"/>
```

Comment: If I use Android Studio instead of Eclipse or any other IDE to write android applications it seems clear to me that I have to write it ...

Comment: can you add your xml code

Comment: Added the XML Switch, no other component in XML =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved with uninstalling application from real device and reinstalling afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

**Create style for your switch.**

```
 <style name="CustomSwitchStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/mediumGray</item>
 <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
```

**Use this xml for switch.**

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/protezione"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:checked="false"       
    android:text="Protezione"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/datas"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/datas"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datas"
    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitchStyle"/>
```

Comment: Nothing change =(

Comment: LOL i have solved with unistall app from real device and redebugging :D